# redefine and declare property in RDFS

Tags: semantic-web, schema.org, rdfs

I want to create a RDFS schema about venue info which contains for example:

address info.

I find another schema about it:https://schema.org/Place which has the property address info.

The first question is **can I declare the Venue also has the property of address?**
I already know that I can use the property without declaring it. The reason I want to declare it to make my schema more clear.

```xml
   <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:place="https://schema.org/Place#"
    xml:base="http://localhost:3000/VenueSchema#">

    <rdfs:Class rdf:ID="Venue">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="https://schema.org/Place"/>
    </rdfs:Class>

    <rdf:Property rdf:ID="address">
        <rdf:type source:"https://schema.org/Place#address">
    </rdf:Property>

    </rdf:RDF>
```

The second question is **can I redefine the property address? Can it achieve override or overload effects?**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<rdf:RDF
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
xmlns:place="https://schema.org/Place#"
xml:base="http://localhost:3000/VenueSchema#">

 <rdfs:Class rdf:ID="Venue">
 <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="https://schema.org/Place"/>
 </rdfs:Class>

  <rdf:Property rdf:ID="address">
  <rdfs:domain rdf:resource= "#Venue">
  <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Literal"/>
 </rdf:Property>

</rdf:RDF>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first question is can I declare the Venue also has the property of
>   address? I already know that I can use the property without declaring
>   it. The reason I want to declare it to make my schema more clear.

Classes *don't have properties* in RDFS.  Properties can have declared domains and ranges, but that doesn't make properties *belong* to classes.  When you say that

p rdfs:domain D

you're saying that when **x p y**, you can *infer* that **x rdf:type D**.  That's all the domain axiom does.  The range axiom is similar, but lets you infer a type for **y**.  You can declare *additional* domains and ranges on a property, but be aware that that means that you'll be able to infer that with that property belong to all the domains.  E.g., if you say that:

hasFoot rdfs:domain Elephant

and

hasFoot rdfs:domain Human

then when you see that **Jimbo hasFoot foot73**, you're going to be able to infer that **Jimbo** is a Human and an Elephant.

> The second question is can I redefine the property address? Can it
>   achieve override or overload effects?

You can say additional things about resources;  that's one of the wonderful things about the Semantic Web.  However, you can't make anyone else retract what they've said about, though you're free to ignore what they've said.  That is, you can include declarations of a property even if someone else has already declared them.  The RDF data model is based on a *set* of triples, and triples don't include duplicates, so there's no difference whether you say something once or a hundred times.

It doesn't make sense to talk about overriding or overloading, though.  I've said it before in the answers to some of your earlier questions, but **RDF is not an object oriented programming language, even though it has a notion of properties and classes.**  A property is just an IRI. It doesn't have any behavior or side effects.  You can say additional things about a property, and you ignore things that others have said about them, but there's sense in which you can override or overload a property.

You can define subproperties, which might be useful.  E.g., you can say:

```
:hasParent a rdfs:Property ;
           rdfs:range :Human .

:hasMother a rdfs:Property ;
           rdfs:range :Woman ;
           rdfs:subPropertyOf :hasParent .
```

If you do this, then when you say **x hasMother y**, you can infer that **y** is a **Woman** and a **Human**, and you can infer that **x hasParent y**.

Comment: Suppose :   hasParent a rdfs:Property ;rdfs:range :Human .  defined in file1.  When I only wrote in file2 without mentioning range and domain and only have: hasParent source:file1#hasParent. Does the file2 has the range and domain in file1?

Comment: @AlexWei I don't know what "hasParent source:file1#hasParent." is supposed to mean.  If you don't load the first file, then you won't have the content in the first file.

Comment: Here I mean in file 2: I want to specify the hasParent is already defined in file1. Will the file2 get the range and domain in file1 in this way?

Comment: "I want to specify the hasParent is already defined in file1" How would you do that?  There's not a way to do that. With an OWL ontology, you can *import* another ontology, but there's no concept of that in RDFS.

Comment: In file 2, Property hasParent<rdf:type rdf:resource="file1#hasParent"/> The range and domain is specified in file1. So the file2 can not get the domain and range in file1, it it right?